# Terraform for_each loop

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So i want to specify gateway_id to the route table but i am getting this:

```
Error: Missing resource instance key

    on modules/vpc/main.tf line 55, in resource "aws_route_table" "RT":
    55:       gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.id
 
    Because aws_internet_gateway.igw has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on
    specific instances.
 
    For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
     aws_internet_gateway.igw[each.key]`
```

variables.tf

```
variable "vpc" {
    type = map(object({
        cidr = string
        tags = map(string)
    }))
    default = {
      "main" = {
        cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
        tags = {
          "Name" = "Main-Vpc"
        }
      }
    }
}

# Subnets

variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    cidr = string
    tags = map(string)
  }))
  # Privates
  default = {
    "Private1" = {
      cidr = "10.0.10.0/24"
      tags = {
        "Name" = "Private1"
      }
    }
    "Private2" = {
        cidr = "10.0.20.0/24"
        tags = {
            "Name" = "Private2"
        }
    }
    #Publcs 
    "Public1" = {
        cidr = "10.0.1.0/24"
        tags = {
            "Name" = "Public1"
        }
    }
    "Public2" = {
        cidr = "10.0.2.0/24"
        tags = {
            "Name" = "Public2"
        }
    }
  }
}

# Route tables

variable "route-tables" {
  type = map(object({
    cidr_block = string
    tags  = map(string)
  }))
  default = {
    "Public1" = {
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      tags = {
        "Name" = "Public1"
      }
    }
    "Public2" = {
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      tags = {
        "Name" = "Public2"
      }
    }
    "Private1" = {
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      tags = {
        "Name" = "Private1"
      }
    }
    "Private2" = {
      cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
      tags = {
        "Name" = "Private2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
    for_each = var.vpc
    cidr_block = each.value["cidr"]
    tags = each.value["tags"]
}


 
# Creting Privates and Public
resource "aws_subnet" "subnets" {
    vpc_id = aws_vpc.main["main"].id
    for_each = var.subnets
    cidr_block = each.value["cidr"]
    tags = each.value["tags"]

    depends_on = [
      aws_vpc.main
    ]
}

# Gateways and Elastic ip
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "igw" {
  for_each = aws_vpc.main
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main["main"].id
}

resource "aws_eip" "elastic" {
  vpc = true
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.elastic.id
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.subnets["Public1"].id

  tags = {
    "Name" = "nat-gateway"
  }

  depends_on = [
    aws_internet_gateway.igw
  ]
}

# Route tables
resource "aws_route_table" "RT" {
  for_each = var.route-tables
  tags = each.value["tags"]
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main["main"].id

  dynamic "route" {
    for_each = var.route-tables
    content {
      cidr_block = route.value.cidr_block
      gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw["main"].id
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to get the value of created resource igw but i dont know how to do it when im using for_each . Also i'm not sure how can i debug this to check the output of the internet_gateway resource!

Edit: I'm posting my full code if needed to analyze maybe will help!

Comment: If I recall correctly, you had a similar question a few days ago about NAT gateway. It would be good to see the part of code where the VPC is created, otherwise the error is pretty clear.

Comment: Uhm it's not me that i asked about NAT i dont have previous post to related topic. https://github.com/InZeinly/vpc-with-for-each/blob/main/modules/vpc/main.tf vpc's is created here also u can look up and gather more related information in same repo

Comment: Sorry, my bad then, it sounded a lot like that question. It would be great to see the code here as well because it might help others if the github repo goes away.

Comment: I'm currently at work i will edit the post and add the vpc creation code in my lunch break.

Comment: Yeah, so you were lucky enough to have only one VPC created with `for_each` whose key is `main` so that's why it would work. Can you please elaborate if the answer you got helped or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To debug such an issue, run `Terraform console` on your terminal, type `aws_internet_gateway.igw` and run `enter`,

it will show you how many items are created by this resource, and it will give you an idea how to reference your igw ID,

from your code I assume referencing your igw ID by `gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.igw.["main"].id` will work, but I'm not sure,

use `Terrafrom console` to confirm.

UPDATE :

it worked because you didn't pass a value for the variable  `var.vpc`, so terraform used the default value and thus create just one vpc resource with the key 'main'

if you run terraform plan, you'll see :

```
aws_vpc.main["main"] will be created
  + resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
      + arn                                  = (known after apply)
      + cidr_block                           = "10.0.0.0/16"
      + default_network_acl_id               = (known after apply)
      + default_route_table_id               = (known after apply)
      + default_security_group_id            = (known after apply)
      + dhcp_options_id                      = (known after apply)
```

and when you did `for_each = aws_vpc.main` on the igw resource, `for_each` received a map of one element with a key "main", so it created just one igw resource with the same key of the vpc which is `main`
so we were able to reference it by  `aws_internet_gateway.igw.["main"].id`

if you have instead multiple items on the var.vpc variable like

```
variable "vpcs" {
    type = map(object({
        cidr = string
        tags = map(string)
    }))
    default = {
      "main" = {
        cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
        tags = {
          "Name" = "Main-Vpc"
        }
      }
         "boo" = {
        cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
        tags = {
          "Name" = "Main-Vpc"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

this will create two vpcs with keys `main`, `boo`, and as you're using `var.vpcs` as the `for_each` value of the igw resource, it will create two igw with the same keys `main`, and `boo`

Comment: When u run aws_internet_gateway.igw in the console it's says only " (known after apply) " I tried to add the line as you said and i think it's worked. When i run plan i can see where the route_tables are created it's says gateway_id = (known after apply) . And by the way can i know why i used "main" and it worked im still not sure yet.